# Coq: How to rewrite inside a lambda?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Basically, I want to prove the following lemma, but I'm having trouble since I can't seem to directly rewrite inside of the lambdas.

However I feel like this should be possible, because if I were "inside" the lambda, I could easily prove it for any given `x`.

```
Lemma lemma :
  forall {A B : Type} (f : A -> B) (g : A -> B), 
    (forall (x : A), f x = g x) -> (fun x => f x) = (fun x => g x).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you're trying to prove is (essentially) functional extentionality, which [is well-known](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/The-Logic-of-Coq#axioms) to not be provable in Coq without extra axioms. Basically, the idea is that `f` and `g` can be intentionally very different (their definitions can look different), but still take on the same values. Equality of functions `(fun x => f x) = (fun x => g x)` would (without any additional axioms) imply that the two functions are syntactically the same.

For example, take `f(n) = 0` and `g(n) = 1 if x^(3 + n) + y^(3 + n) = z^(3 + n) has a non-trivial solution in integers, otherwise 0` (both functions from natural numbers to natural numbers). Then `f` and `g` are intentionally different - one doesn't syntactically reduce to the other. However, thanks to Andrew Wiles, we know that `f` and `g` are extentionally the same since `g(n) = 0` for all `n`.

You can freely add your lemma (or various strengthenings) as an axiom to Coq without worrying about inconsistency.

Comment: A minor clarification on syntactic comparison of functions: when Coq compares functions it takes into account computational rules, e.g. these two functions are equal: `Check eq_refl : (fun n => n) = (fun m => (fun n => 0 + n) m).`.